# why is the cmd window not responding

Tags: windows, keyboard, ftp, command-line

I just have found the command `ftp` in cmd world

I am quite happy because that means I don't need an ftp client but when I try to log-on
and it prompts me for a password my keyboard does not respond

except enter and once I do that the password command is finished
is this my problem of is there something special I have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your keyboard isn't responding? Most password prompts don't echo anything when you enter your password (to prevent shoulder surfing). (Some show a `*` for each character; this doesn't mean all your keys have been remapped to `*`.) Isn't your password working?

Comment: @Luck: In other words, this is intentional behavior.  Just type your password normally in even though you don't see anything on the screen.

Comment: heh look it worked